# Should I store logged-in user data on `g` or on `session`?

Tags: python, session, flask

I'm reading through [this part on logins from a Flask tutorial.](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins)
In this example, the author stores the User object on the `g` global.

Why does he do that? Doesn't it make much more sense to store logged-in user data on the `session` global? Shouldn't I use `session` to store data about the logged in user?

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't make sense to do what you describe.  Flask-Login *does* store user information in the session: it stores the user id in order to load the full user on each request.

If you just stored the user data on the session, it would get out of sync if the user had more than two browser sessions, or something that changed user data occurred outside the user's control.

You pass a `User` instance to Flask-Login's `login_user` function, and it will store the user's id in the `session`.  When the next request comes in, it will call the `user_loader` with this stored id to retrieve the user instance again.  The instance is stored in `g` for the duration of the request.

Answer (score -1):

In theory, either `session` or `g` could work for storing the logged-in user.

In Flask-Login, the main purpose of the `session` cookie is to track the user id. Flask-Login does the rest to get and store the user object during a request in `g`.

`g` is more flexible than `session`. Anything added to `session` must be JSON serializable. `g` is a Python object, so any data, including objects and even functions, can be assigned to it (`g.user`, `g.some_function()`, etc.) and used during the request.

By default, all data stored in the `session` is stored in a browser cookie that is securely signed by ItsDangerous. The cookie is sent to the server by the browser with each request. Anyone with access to the user's connection could intercept and read the data in it, although they would not be able to change it due to the signature.

In contrast, `g` is only stored in server memory during each request. None of the data will be visible to the user or others. However, it is not persistent, and must be recreated for each request. The `session` cookie retains its data across requests.